# Combine colums from table return multiple times the same record

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have 2 tables `INVENTORY` and `PRODUCTS` and I want to select some columns of the `INVENTORY` and one from the `PRODUCTS`. I wrote:

```
SELECT INVENTORY.product, INVENTORY.version, PRODUCTS.customer
FROM INVENTORY
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS ON
INVENTORY.product = PRODUCTS.product AND INVENTORY.version= PRODUCTS.version
```

and I get multiple times the same records.. How I fix it?

Comment: What exactly should be fixed? Tables contents, Db design, query results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple distinct or group by:

```
SELECT DISTINCT INVENTORY.product, INVENTORY.version, PRODUCTS.customer
FROM INVENTORY
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS ON
INVENTORY.product = PRODUCTS.product AND INVENTORY.version= PRODUCTS.version
```

Or :

```
SELECT INVENTORY.product, INVENTORY.version, PRODUCTS.customer
FROM INVENTORY
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS ON
INVENTORY.product = PRODUCTS.product AND INVENTORY.version= PRODUCTS.version
GROUP BY INVENTORY.product, INVENTORY.version, PRODUCTS.customer
```